# Table not outputting all columns

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop, html-table

I am having a nightmare with this pretty simple table I have. I am trying to create a draft type board. I have users and players. I want users to be displayed as the `<th>` and then 14 players `<td>` under each player. Somewhat like this..

http://lockerroomfantasysports.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/FantasySports-Fantasy-Football-Draft-Board.jpg

However, my page is showing up like this...
[image]

It is only creating two columns of players for the users. Rather than one for each. It is also not displaying the db content where it should be. The player that is shown should only be in the first location it is (the left one).

This is the code for it.

```
$draft_order_stmt = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_players ORDER BY `id`");
$draft_order_stmt2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username FROM user_players ORDER BY `id`");

?>
<table class="draft_border_table">
    <tr>
        <th class="draft_table_number_th">RND</th>
<?php

while ($draft_user_row = mysqli_fetch_array($draft_order_stmt2)) {

    $username = $draft_user_row['username'];

    echo "<th class='draft_table_th'><div>" . $username . "</div></th>";

}
?>

    </tr>

<?php
for ($count = 1; $count < 15; $count++) { 

$col = "player" . $count; 
$query = "SELECT $col FROM user_players ORDER BY id"; 
$draft_order_stmt2 = mysqli_query($con, $query); 

$draft_order_row = mysqli_fetch_array($draft_order_stmt2); 

echo "<tr><td>" . $count . "</td>"; 

foreach ($draft_order_row as $player) { 

echo "<td><div class=\"draftBorder\">"; 

if (is_null($player)) {

$player = "&nbsp;";

}

echo $player . "</div></td>"; 

} 

echo "</tr>"; 
}
?>
</table>
```

I also tried this initially and it is displaying all of the player inputs, but the player inputs are all in one block. Like this...

user1 user2 user3

all 14 player inputs

Again all 14 player inputs

Again all 14 player inputs

etc..

This is my code for that...

```
$draft_order_stmt = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_players ORDER BY `id`");
$draft_order_stmt2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username FROM user_players ORDER BY `id`");
?>
<table class="draft_border_table">
            <tr>
                <th>Rnd</th>

<?php 
while($draft_username_row = mysqli_fetch_array($draft_order_stmt2)) {
    $username = $draft_username_row['username'];
?>

                <th><?php echo "<div>" . $username . "</div>"; ?></th>
<?php
}
?>
            </tr>
<?php
$count = 1;
while($draft_order_row = mysqli_fetch_array($draft_order_stmt)) {
    $count + 1;
    $player1 = $draft_order_row['player1'];
    $player2 = $draft_order_row['player2'];
    $player3 = $draft_order_row['player3'];
    $player4 = $draft_order_row['player4'];
    $player5 = $draft_order_row['player5'];
    $player6 = $draft_order_row['player6'];
    $player7 = $draft_order_row['player7'];
    $player8 = $draft_order_row['player8'];
    $player9 = $draft_order_row['player9'];
    $player10 = $draft_order_row['player10'];
    $player11 = $draft_order_row['player11'];
    $player12 = $draft_order_row['player12'];
    $player13 = $draft_order_row['player13'];
    $player14 = $draft_order_row['player14'];
?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player1 . "</div>"; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player2 . "</div>"; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player3 . "</div>"; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player4 . "</div>"; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player5 . "</div>"; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player6 . "</div>"; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player7 . "</div>"; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player8 . "</div>"; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player9 . "</div>"; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player10 . "</div>"; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player11 . "</div>"; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player12 . "</div>"; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player13 . "</div>"; ?></td>

                <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player14 . "</div>"; ?></td>
            </tr>

<?php
}
?>
        </table>
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Looks like you accidentally overwrite the content of `$draft_order_stmt2`, so you lose the result of the second query you made in the second row of the first script.

Comment: This line? `1$draft_order_stmt2 = mysqli_query($con, $query);` How else could I do it then?

Comment: Well, use another, third variable to save the result of that third statement.

Comment: Looking at your code, this will make each column heading the usernames of your users and then each row the users players... which doesn't correlate players to each user. Do you want usernames as the first column and players to the right, or usernames as column headings and players as vertically below them? Also what is the meaning of the column RND?

Comment: @DanBelden I want that usernames as the column heading and the players associated with them vertically below them. RND is just short for round. This is just for a user draft.

Comment: Got ya, solutions will now start trickling in.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it! @DanBelden

Comment: @arkascha I did this and it didn't help.. `$draft_order_stmt3 = mysqli_query($con, $query); 

$draft_order_row = mysqli_fetch_array($draft_order_stmt3); `

Comment: Sorry, it was just something obvious that stood out. I have to admit that I did not work through that wall of code you posted.

Comment: I understand. I just wanted to show things I've tried to potentially help with an answer. I thought this table would take me 5 minutes and I've been stuck on it for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $userPlayerStore = array(); ?>

<table class="draft_border_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Rnd</th>

<?php

// Output usernames as column headings
$userResults = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM user_players ORDER BY `id`');
while($userPlayer = mysqli_fetch_array($userResults)) {
    $userPlayerStore[] = $userPlayer;
    echo '<th><div>' . $userPlayer['username'] . '</div></th>';
}

?>

    </tr>

<?php

// Output each user's player 1-14 in each row
$totalPlayerNumbers = 14;
for ($playerNum = 1; $playerNum <= $totalPlayerNumbers; $playerNum++) {
    echo '<tr><td><div class="draftBorder">' . $playerNum . '</div></td>';
    foreach ($userPlayerStore as $userPlayer) {
        echo '<td><div class="draftBorder">' . $userPlayer['player' . $playerNum] . '</div></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

?>

</table>
```

Comment: Hi again, I don't want to bug you, but please if you can, will you look at this. I tried to change the player echo to this... ` foreach ($userPlayerStore as $userPlayer) {
    echo '<td><div class="draftBorder">' . $userPlayer['player' . ' - ' . 'position' . $playerNum] . '</div></td>';` .... I added position's to my db, just as I did my players, so I thought I could just add it to the echo, but it is throwing undefined index errors. Any idea how I could add that?

Comment: I created a new question for it here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421942/issues-adding-a-set-of-database-columns-to-array ... If you could help, I'd appreciate it so much! If not, then I appreciate everything you have already done!